# Update quote after unlocking it in screen flow

Tags: approval-process, quote, screen-flow

I have a business requirement that lets a the user - who submitted a `Quote` record for approval - update it if he wants to.

For this, I created a `screen flow`. I start by unlocking the record and then I proceed to update it an locking it later. But I get an error saying that unlocking a record and updating it in the same transaction is impossible :

```
ENTITY_IS_LOCKED
```

this is my flow :

[image]

is there any work-around? Since this is a screen flow there is no asynchronous path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the admin can modify a record even if it's locked, I modified the flow so it would run without sharing.

[image]